# Why isn't my PHP able to connect to MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to connect to my MySQL database using the following PHP code

```
<?php

require "credentials.php";

$conn = mysqli_connect($hostname, $username, $password, $databaseName);

if(mysqli_connect_errno())
{
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

?>
```

And I am getting the following output:

```
Failed to connect to MySQL: Connection refused
```

What could be the reasons that this is happening, and how can I fix it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "Connection refused" suggests a firewall is blocking the request, or maybe more likely the MySQL port isn't open at all because the server isn't running.  Make sure the MySQL service is available. If you are connecting to a local server, try with `localhost` instead of `127.0.0.1` as the connection host. If it's a remote host, contact the administrator of that host to get access  through its firewall.

Comment: Are you sure mysqld service is up and running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from your code it seems that you are using undefined variables to connect to database. if you load them from external file, than use something like this in that file:

```
define("DBPASSWORD", "database_pass");
define("DBUSERNAME", "databaseusername");
define("DBNAME", "database");
define("DBHOST", "database_host");
```

and than use in file you shown us:

```
$conn = mysqli_connect(DBHOST, DBUSERNAME, DBPASSWORD, DBNAME);
```

OR another way, the way I can't recomend is using globals.

**WARNING: I discourage using globals, when not needed.**

Your credentials.php should look like that:

```
global $databaseName;
global $password;
global $username;
global $username;
$databaseName= "db_name";
$password= "db_password";
$username= "db_username";
$hostname= "db_host";
```

and than in other places, first you need to call the globals before usage.

```
require "credentials.php";

global $databaseName;
global $password;
global $username;
global $username;

$conn = mysqli_connect($hostname, $username, $password, $databaseName);
```